# AttributeError - webscraping - Python - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I need scrape the following table from the web and I cannot solve the issue with "find_all" function. The PyCharm always says:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I dont know what is wrong. Trying it with table.find_all("tr") or table.find_all('tr') characters and with next attributes like table.find_all("tr", attrs={"class": "table table-export"}) and next options and nothing works.
Please could you tell me what I doing wrong?

Table:

```
<div class="table-options">
    <table class="table table-export">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!-- ngIf: ActuallyPoints && ActuallyPoints.name == 'AXB' --><th ng-if="currentRole &amp;&amp; currentRole.name == 'AXB'" class="id check">
                        <label ng-click="selectAll()"><input disabled="" id="select-all" type="checkbox" ng-model="all" class="valid value-ng">All</label>
                    </th><!-- end ngIf: currentRole && currentRole.name == 'AXB' -->
                    <th>AAA</th>
                    <th>BBB</th>
                    <th>CCC</th>
        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<!-- ngRepeat: x in ErrorStatus --><tr ng-repeat="x in ErrorStatus" class="random-id">
                    <!-- ngIf: currentRole && currentRole.name == 'AXB' --><td ng-if="currentRole &amp;&amp; currentRole.name == 'AXB'" class="random-id">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.checked" ng-change="selectOne(x)" class="valid value-ng">
                    </td><!-- end ngIf: currentRole && currentRole.name == 'AXB' -->
                    <td class="pax">111</td>
                    <td class="pax">222</td>
                    <td class="pax">333</td>
                    </td>
                </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: x in ErrorStatus -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Code:

```
import lxml
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'xxx'
website = request.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(website, "lxml")

table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table table-export"})
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

Many thanks.

Comment: what is the url that your trying to scrape.. pls add it in your code

Comment: I am sorry but this is a private url with confidential database and unfortunately I cannot share it with everyone and the login is neccessary..

Comment: then I'm afraid you'll get little to no help in here.. if others can't replicate the problem in real time, then its not worth solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't be able to provide a solution, since there is no link, but explanation to the error is quite simple:

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Let's see where you use `.find_all` in you code:

```py
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

Considering what interpreter says, this piece of code actually looks like:

```py
rows = None.find_all('tr')
```

In other words, your variable `table` equals `None`. Therefore, your problem is here:

```py
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table table-export"}) # returns None
```

In human language, you were trying to find some table within your html and then store it to variable `table`, but `soup.find()` wasn't able to find the element, using the instructions you gave, and therefore returned `None`. You didn't notice it and tried to call `None.find_all()`, but `None` doesn't have this method.

That's why you receive this error. If you can't share the link, please re-check this piece by yourself, since it's not working:

```py
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table table-export"}) # returns None
```

UPD: First of all, try printing variable `soup` and check if the table is present, because html, which you see at browser, and html, which you receive by request, might be quite different:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(website, "lxml")
print(soup)
```